# How to replace elements with specific values in a 3D matrix with their previus data in Python?

Tags: python, matrix, while-loop

I have a 3D matrix (lon, lat, hight) which some elements have the value 0. I want to replace those values with the data in their previus level until all zero data are replaced. It means that if 'a' is the matrix[i, j, k], then I want to replace the zero values in it with [i,j,k-1] and if the previous value is zero again it takes the previus data until it gets value. I have tried the code below but it gives error and what ever that I do the result is nonesense. LW is a nc file.

```
LW = S.netcdf_file('/path','r')
a = LW.variables['nflx'][:,:,:]
lona = LW.variables['lon'][:]
lata = LW.variables['lat'][:]

M = np.zeros([96,73,25])
for i in xrange(0, 96):
  for j in xrange(0, 73):
    for k in xrange(0,25):
        while a==0:
           M = a[:,:,k-1]

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Does anybody have any idea about it? All helps are appreciated.

Comment: Please check the variables `M` and `a` in your example. `M` is an array but get a scalar and `a` is an undefined array.

Comment: Yes. It is the matrix with 3 dimension [i,j,k] which has been defined in the previous part of the code. I have just defined the M as a new matrix but is is the same as 'a' with zeros replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an easy and dynamic way. Every subarray M[i,j] will be handled as loop. If the first value is zero, it will be replaced by the last value.

```
>>> M = np.arange(20)
... M[[6,11,12,19]] = 0
... M = M.reshape((2,2,5))
... print(M)
[[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
  [ 5  0  7  8  9]]

 [[10  0  0 13 14]
  [15 16 17 18  0]]]
>>> for i in np.ndindex(M.shape[:-1]):
...     while 0 in M[i]:
...         args = np.argwhere(M[i]==0)
...         M[i][args] = M[i][args-1]
... print(M)
[[[ 4  1  2  3  4]
  [ 5  5  7  8  9]]

 [[10 10 10 13 14]
  [15 16 17 18 18]]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when you put M[:,:,10] = 1.0, it is just that level which has value 1.0 and the rest of them are all zero. I just added the first part of my code which 'a' is defined. When I used 'a' instead of 'M' I had this error: RuntimeError: array is not writeable?

Comment: I edited my answer with output of example values how I understood your problem. If that is not correct add a small example of your matrix you have and how it should look like similar I did, please.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is definitely the best answer for my case! Feeling relieved after couple of days struggling with that problem! Thanks again.